# Regression Summaries in R

Tags: r, sorting, statistics, regression

I've been using the `glm` function to do regression analysis, and it's treating me quite well. I'm wondering though, some of the things I want to regress involve a large amount of regression factors. I have two main questions:

1. Is it possible to give a text vector for the regressors?
2. Can the p-value portion of `summary(glm)` be sorted at all? Preferably by the p-values of each regressor.

Ex.

```
A # sample data frame
names(A)
[1] Dog Cat Human Limbs Tail Height Weight Teeth.Count
a = names(A)[4:7]
glm( Dog ~ a, data = A, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: You can specify all of the remaining columns in a matrix using something like: `glm(A$Dog ~ ., data = A[,4:7])`.

Comment: That you want to order output by p-values hints at statistical misconceptions on your part. But, like almost anything in R, it can be done.

Comment: I'm a mathematician, not a statistician, but aren't the p-values the indication of the probability that the result is random? Thus, the strength of the regressor is the associated p-value?

Comment: @riders994, no the strength of the effect and its significance are two different things. For the former you need to consider the size of the effect, e.g. by comparing standardized coefficients or using Cohen's test for effect size. Also, I imagine that variables in your model will be highly correlated (e.g. Height & Weight), which means you will have serious multicollinearity issues, and unreliable model as result.

Comment: My actual data is much more complicated, and I've been seeing multicollinearity issues in it. I'll look up these tests you're describing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, see `as.formula`. Basically you want to do the following:

```
x <- names(A)[4:7]
regressors <- paste(x,collapse=" + ")
form <- as.formula(c("Dog ~ ",regressors))
glm(form, data = A, family = "binomial")
```

If you want interaction terms in your model, you need to make the structure somewhat more complex by using different `collapse=` arguments. That argument specifies which symbols are placed between the elements of your vector. For instance, if you specify `"*"` in the code above, you will have a saturated model with all possible interactions. If you just need some interactions, but not all, you will want to create the part of the formula containing all interactions first (using "*" as collapse argument), and then add the remaining terms in the separate paste function (using "+" as collapse argument). All in all, you want to create a character string that is identical to your formula, and then convert it to the formula class.

For your second question, you need to convert the output of summary to a data structure that can be sorted. For instance, a data frame. Let's say that the name of your glm model is `model`:

```
library(plyr)
coef <- summary(model)[12]
coef.sort <- as.data.frame(coef)
names(coef.sort) <- c("Estimate","SE","Tval","Pval")
arrange(coef.sort,Pval)
```

Assign the result of `arrange()` to a varable, and continue with it as you like.

Answer (score 4):

An example data frame:

```
set.seed(42)
A <- data.frame(Dog = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE), b = rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100))
a <- names(A)[2:3]
```

Firstly, you can use the character vector `a` to create a model formula with `reformulate`:

```
glm(Dog ~ a, data = A, family = "binomial")

form <- reformulate(a, "Dog")
# Dog ~ b + c

model <- glm(form, data = A, family = "binomial")
```

Secondly, this is a way to sort the model summary by the p-values:

```
modcoef <- summary(model)[["coefficients"]]

modcoef[order(modcoef[ , 4]), ]         

#                Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
# b            0.23902684  0.2212345  1.0804232 0.2799538
# (Intercept)  0.20855908  0.2025642  1.0295951 0.3032001
# c           -0.09287769  0.2191231 -0.4238608 0.6716673
```